# Showing that the lower bivariate Fréchet-Hoeffding bound is a copula.

Tags: upper-lower-bounds, copula

I want to show that the bivariate Fréchet-Hoefdding lower bound is indeed a copula.

The bivariate function is defined by:  $W(x,y)=\max\{x+y-1,0\}, \ x,y\in[0,1] $

Definition "Copula":
A two-dimensional copula is a function $A:\left[ 0,1\right]^2\rightarrow \left[ 0,1\right]$ with the following two properties:

1. $\forall x\in \left[ 0,1 \right]:A(x,1)=A(1,x)=x$, $A(x,0)=A(0,x)=0$.
2. For $0\leq x_1 \leq x_2 \leq 1$ and $ 0 \leq y_1 \leq y_2 \leq 1$ the following inequality holds:
   $$
   A(x_2,y_2)-A(x_1,y_2)-A(x_2,y_1)+A(x_1,y_1) \geq 0
   $$

I want to show that $W(x,y)$ is a copula by verifying the properties in the definition.
I already managed to show the first property, but I'm struggling with the second one.

Ad property 1: For all $x,y\in [0,1]$ the following holds:
$$
W(x,1)=\max\{x+1-1,0\}=x=\max\{1+x-1,0\}= W(1,x)
$$
$$
W(x,0)=\max\{x+0-1,0\}=0=\max\{0+x-1,0\}=W(0,x).
$$
Ad property 2: I think I have to differ between several cases, but I don't know exactly how to describe the cases.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**HINT**

Consider the upper triangle defined by

\begin{align*}
U := \{(x,y)\in[0,1]^{2}\mid y \geq 1 - x\}
\end{align*}

For every $(x,y)\in U$, we have that $\max\{x + y - 1,0\} = x + y - 1$.

Similarly, consider the lower triangle defined by
\begin{align*}
L := \{(x,y)\in[0,1]^{2} \mid y \leq 1 - x\}
\end{align*}

For every $(x,y)\in L$, we have that $\max\{x + y - 1,0\} = 0$.

Now study every possible configuration of the box $B = [x_{1},x_{2}]\times[y_{1},y_{2}]$.

Can you take it from here?

Comment: Okay, if i got this right, then i have a box like this:
$(x_2,y_2),(x_1,y_2),(x_2,y_1),(x_1,y_1)$ and each tuple can be in $U$ or in $L$.
So alltogether there are 16 cases and for example one case would look like this:
For $(x_2,y_2),(x_1,y_2)\in L$ and $(x_2,y_1),(x_1,y_1)\in U$ then:
$$ \begin{aligned}
 A(x_2,y_2)-A(x_1,y_2)-A(x_2,y_1)+A(x_1,y_1) &= 0-0-x_2+y_1+1+x_1+y_1+1\\
&\geq -1+2y_1+x_1+2\\
&=2y_1+x_1+1 \geq 0
\end{aligned}$$

Is this right?

Comment: You are on the right track. Notice, however, there are not 16 possibilities. If I am not wrong, there are only 5 possibilities. Moreover, don't forget that $x_{2}\geq x_{1}$ and $y_{2}\geq y_{1}$. You miscalculated the $A$ volume as it is in your comment: it is not possible that $(x_{2},y_{2})\in L$ and $(x_{2},y_{1})\in U$.

Comment: Oh, i blundered there.
Considering that, the possible cases are:  
For 1st case : $(x_2,y_2),(x_1,y_2),(x_2,y_1),(x_1,y_1)\in U$, and  
2nd case: $(x_2,y_2),(x_1,y_2),(x_2,y_1),(x_1,y_1)\in L$, and  
3rd case: $(x_2,y_2),(x_2,y_1)\in U,(x_1,y_2),(x_1,y_1)\in L$, we have:  
$$A(x_2,y_2)-A(x_1,y_2)-A(x_2,y_1)+A(x_1,y_1)=0$$

4th case: $(x_2,y_2),(x_1,y_2)\in U,(x_2,y_1),(x_1,y_1)\in L$, then:
$$A(x_2,y_2)-A(x_1,y_2)-A(x_2,y_1)+A(x_1,y_1)=x_2-x_1\geq 0$$

5th case: $(x_2,y_2)\in U,(x_1,y_2),(x_2,y_1),(x_1,y_1)\in L$, then:
$$A(x_2,y_2)-A(x_1,y_2)-A(x_2,y_1)+A(x_1,y_1)=x_2-y_2-1\geq 0$$